# Performance impact while writing Write Ahead Logs for streaming data in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Is writing Write Ahead Log(WAL) for streaming data in spark an expensive operation in terms of performance and throughput? It would be very helpful if I get some performance metrics for WAL.

Answer (score 2):

Better not to use WAL if the source is kafka. It's better to store the offset for each partition for each topic into zookeeper. When application starts, it will take the last stored offset from zookeeper and start processing the next event.
In my case, the source was kafka, and it got resolved by storing the offset to zookeeper. It's more effective rather than writing WAL which will significantly minimize the throughput of your application.